# Wcf.js module to access wcf services from nodejs

Tags: wcf, node.js

I  have a requirement to access a wcf webservice from my node server.I came across a module called wcf.js which was rated for that purpose.But am confused with the part of message can anyone give me an explanation as how to code using that module will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The codeproject article at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/379389/Wcf-js-Call-WCF-web-services-from-Node-js has some examples of how to call a WCF service using that package. And the [project's page on GitHub](https://github.com/yaronn/wcf.js) also has some documentation.

In the GitHub project you can also find some examples, and the tests for this project (and for any project, in general) are always a good starting point to see how one would use a framework.